Calculate amount with value and calculation type (set, fixed, seconds, persentages, second persentages) and have the correct stat changed
I need help with the following.
Calculate with only a amount variable and an enum to set what type of calculation so i can set the correct stat value to a stat.
Make sure the correct stat gets changed.
So in other words make sure the correct stat gets changed by the correct amount.
Here is the code i have so far (the only script that i think needs to change is the PlayerStatCalculator script)
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerStatCalculator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CardSO collectedCard;
    public PlayerStats playerStatToChange;


    public void OnCardCollected()
    {
        //piece of code to activate abilities

        foreach (var statChanges in collectedCard.StatChanges)
        {
            SetStats(statChanges.statChangeAmount, statChanges.changeType);
            //statChanges.statName

        }
    }

    void SetStats(float amount, EStatChangeType type)
    {
        float statToChange = 0;// this needs to become the stat that needs to be changed in playerStatToChange


        switch (type)
        {
            case EStatChangeType.Fixed:
                statToChange += amount;
                break;
            case EStatChangeType.Persentage:
                
                break;
            case EStatChangeType.Set:
                statToChange = amount;
                break;
            case EStatChangeType.Second:

                break;
            case EStatChangeType.SecondPersentage:

                break;
        }        
    }
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


[CreateAssetMenu]
public class CardSO : ScriptableObject
{
    public string CardName;

    public bool CanGet = true;

    public bool CanSpawn = true;

    public Image CardBG;

    public ECardRarity rarity;

    public EAbilityType abilityType;


    //need to make it so i can only set this if i give the abilityType the correct value
    public EBlockAbility blockAbility;
    public EBulletAbility bulletAbility;
    public EPlayerAbility playerAbility;

    public CardStat[] StatChanges;
}

public enum EAbilityType
{
    None,
    Block,
    Bullet,
    Player
}

public enum EPlayerAbility
{
    None
}

public enum EBlockAbility //things like implosion are going in here
{
    None,
    Bombs_Away
}

public enum EBulletAbility //things like poison cloud are going in here
{
    None,
    Poison,
    Parasite
}

public enum ECardRarity
{
    None,
    common,
    uncommon,
    rare,
    epic,
    legendairy,
    mythic
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu]
public class PlayerStats : ScriptableObject
{
    public int Hp = 100;

    public int Damage = 55;

    public float ReloadTime = 1;
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class CardStat
{
    public EStatToChange statName;
    public EStatChangeType changeType;
    public float statChangeAmount;
}

public enum EStatChangeType
{
    none,
    Fixed,
    Persentage,
    Set,
    Second,
    SecondPersentage
}

public enum EStatToChange
{
    none,
    Hp,
    Damage,
    ReloadTime
}


So in other words make sure the correct stat gets changed by the correct amount. ... so .. what exactly is your question? What hinders you in doing that? I wonder why you are not using the CardStat.statName in order to determine which stat should actually be affected ..... (side note: it is percentage not persentage)

In general you might rather want to go directly with a SerializedDictionary

For anyone wondering this is the answer i was looking for
PropertyInfo is a class available in unity just make sure that you are using System.Reflection; at the top
using System.Reflection

public CardSO collectedCard;
public PlayerStats playerStatToChange;

public void OnCardCollected()
{
    //piece of code to activate abilities

    foreach (var statChanges in collectedCard.StatChanges)
    {
        CalculateStats(statChanges.statChangeAmount, statChanges.changeType, statChanges.statName);
    }
}

void CalculateStats(float amount, EStatChangeType type, EStatToChange stat)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case EStatChangeType.Add:
            AddStat(amount, stat);
            break;

        case EStatChangeType.Persentage:
            PersentageStat(amount, stat);
            break;

        case EStatChangeType.Set:
            SetStat(amount, stat);
            break;

    }
}

void SetStat(float floatAmount, EStatToChange stat)
{
    int intAmount = Mathf.RoundToInt(floatAmount);

    string statName = Enum.GetName(typeof(EStatToChange), stat);
    if (statName == null || statName == "none") return;

    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(PlayerStats).GetProperty(statName);
    if (propertyInfo == null) return;

    if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(int))
    {
        int currentValue = (int)propertyInfo.GetValue(playerStatToChange);
        propertyInfo.SetValue(playerStatToChange, intAmount);
    }
    else if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(float))
    {
        float currentValue = (float)propertyInfo.GetValue(playerStatToChange);
        propertyInfo.SetValue(playerStatToChange, floatAmount);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogWarning($"Unsupported property type for stat {statName}.");
    }
}

void PersentageStat(float amount, EStatToChange stat)
{
    float persentageAmount = 1 + (amount / 100);

    string statName = Enum.GetName(typeof(EStatToChange), stat);
    if (statName == null || statName == "none") return;

    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(PlayerStats).GetProperty(statName);
    if (propertyInfo == null) return;

    if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(int))
    {
        int currentValue = (int)propertyInfo.GetValue(playerStatToChange);
        propertyInfo.SetValue(playerStatToChange, currentValue * 100 * persentageAmount / 100);
    }
    else if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(float))
    {
        float currentValue = (float)propertyInfo.GetValue(playerStatToChange);
        propertyInfo.SetValue(playerStatToChange, currentValue *= persentageAmount);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogWarning($"Unsupported property type for stat {statName}.");
    }
}

void AddStat(float floatAmount, EStatToChange stat)
{
    int intAmount = Mathf.RoundToInt(floatAmount);

    string statName = Enum.GetName(typeof(EStatToChange), stat);
    if (statName == null || statName == "none") return;

    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(PlayerStats).GetProperty(statName);
    if (propertyInfo == null) return;

    if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(int))
    {
        int currentValue = (int)propertyInfo.GetValue(playerStatToChange);
        propertyInfo.SetValue(playerStatToChange, currentValue += intAmount);
    }
    else if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(float))
    {
        float currentValue = (float)propertyInfo.GetValue(playerStatToChange);
        propertyInfo.SetValue(playerStatToChange, currentValue += floatAmount);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogWarning($"Unsupported property type for stat {statName}.");
    }
}


To get an accumulation of stats, given your initial set up, one possible solution could be to use tuples. Your code in PlayerStatCalculator would look something like:
private (int hp, int damage, float reload) SetStats( EStatToChange statToChange, float statAmount, (int hp, int damage, float reload) result )
{
  switch (statToChange)
  {
    case EStatToChange.Hp:
      result.hp += (int) statAmount;
      break;
    case EStatToChange.Damage:
      result.damage += (int) statAmount;
      break;
    case EStatToChange.ReloadTime:
      result.reload += statAmount;
      break;
  }
  return result;
}

And it's usage would be:
// create a default (blank) 'result' variable.
(int hp, int damage, float reload) result = default;

// cycle through your stat changes, feeding in the accumulated 'result' value.
foreach (var statChanges in collectedCard.StatChanges)
  result = SetStats ( statChanges.changeType, statChanges.statChangeAmount, result );

// result now has the accumulated stat values for all stat changes and stat types.
Debug.Log ( $"hp:{result.hp}. damage:{result.damage}. reload:{result.reload}. " );

// You can now store these values in to your player details.

Note that this is a fairly rigid implementation, and doesn't lend itself to be neatly extensible, but will resolve your current requirements.
